# how i can Show error for unique fields in asp.net core

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a problem In association with validation property! I use .net core 2.1. I checked unique fields in OnModelCreating method in DbContext class and it's working fine. now I want to display an error message if the user enters the same BirthCertificate value (already exists in the database) in the input field like that Display & Required & MaxLength & ... attributes and send (bind) it to ModelState to check it. i also use jquery.validate.js in the client and show all errors and it's working fine. how I should do this:

```
Public Class Person
{
   [Display(Name = "Enter BirthCertificate")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
   [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max lenght is {0}")]
   public string BirthCertificate { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<DomainClasses.Person.Person>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.BirthCertificate).IsUnique();  // it's working fine
    });
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one of these.

1) Create new unique key for BirthCertificate in SQL Server. Use catch (Exception ex) and return to ajax to show error.

2) Do checking code

```
if (db.Person.Where(x => x.BirthCertificate.Contains(birthcert)).Any())
{
     //return to ajax to show error
}
```